# Change icon and text of button on button click

Tags: html, jquery

I currently have a button with a span that displays an icon with an arrow, like so:

```html
<button id="btnCollapse" type="button" onClick="hey()" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">
   <span id="iconCollapse" class="glyphicon glyphicon-collapse-down"></span> 
   Collapse Views 
</button>
```

I would want onClick function to instead now say Expand Views, and have the glyphicon-collapse icon to be `up` rather than `down`

Here's what I have come up with:

```js
function hey() {
  var btn  = $("#btnCollapse");
  var span = btn.children("#iconCollapse");
  span.addClass("glyphicon glyphicon-collapse-up");
  btn.html = "Expand Views"
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@3.3.7/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<button id="btnCollapse" type="button" onClick="hey()" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">
    <span id="iconCollapse" class="glyphicon glyphicon-collapse-down"></span> 
    Collapse Views 
  </button>
```

What I am actually trying to achieve is this:

If user clicks on Collapse View - I want to perform some functionality, something along the lines of

```pascal
if (btn.html.contains('Collapase'))
    Then
           //do something
    Else 
           //do something else
```

Comment: `btn[0].innerHTML = "Expand Views";` or In jquery `btn.html("Expand Views");` .. And for check you can use `if(btn.text().trim().indexOf("Collapse") > -1)`

Comment: @Mohamed-Yousef if you change the innerHTML of the button you'll remove the icon

Comment: Don't check the "HTML" of the button - check the classes.  Ideally, add a class to the button itself (eg "expanded" or "collapsed" - classes don't have to have associated styles).   Given what you already have you could do `if (btn.find("#iconCollapse").is(".glyphicon-collapse-up"))`

Comment: @freedomn-m yes I know that but I tried to correct his line `btn.html = "Expand Views"` and to let him know that this line won't work

Comment: @Mohamed-Yousef I see - there's plenty of SO solutions for changing text given OPs layout - easiest is to stick the text part in a span.  Then you don't have HTML in your JS (separation, only if your a stickler).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First: ID should be unique .. That means if you will use multiple `collapse/expand` elements you need to change the `id` to class

Second: if you change the HTML you'll remove the icon so it will be better to wrap the text inside `<span>Collapse</span>` or change all the html like the example below

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@3.3.7/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">


</head>
<body>
  <button type="button" onClick="hey()" class="btnCollapse btn btn-default btn-sm">
    <span class="iconCollapse glyphicon glyphicon-collapse-down"></span> 
    Collapse Views 
  </button>
  

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>

<script>
    function hey(){
      var btn = $(".btnCollapse");
      var span = btn.children(".iconCollapse");
      btn.html(
        btn.text().trim().indexOf("Collapse") > -1 ?
        '<span class="iconCollapse glyphicon glyphicon-collapse-up"></span> Expand Views' 
        : 
        '<span class="iconCollapse glyphicon glyphicon-collapse-down"></span> Collapse Views');
    }
</script>
```

For me this isn't the good way to do that .. But you can use this code temporarily untill you get a best code of it

And the good way to do this is:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@3.3.7/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">


</head>
<body>
  <button type="button" onClick="hey(this)" class="btnCollapse btn btn-default btn-sm">
    <span class="iconCollapse glyphicon glyphicon-collapse-down"></span> 
    <span class="textCollapse">Collapse Views</span> 
  </button>
  

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>

<script>
    function hey(el){
      var btn = $(el);
      var span = btn.find(".iconCollapse");
      var text = btn.find(".textCollapse");
      span.toggleClass("glyphicon-collapse-down glyphicon-collapse-up");
      text.text(span.hasClass("glyphicon-collapse-up") ? "Expand Views" : "Collapse Views");
    }
</script>
```

Comment: But this doesn't show the icon :(

Comment: @Dave123 sorry my bad I added two class attribute and its invalid .. I updated the answer

Comment: @Dave123 Also please take a look at freedomn-m comments in OP it will be helpful

Comment: if this isn't the best way to do it, then what's the better way? I mean my requirements are not complex, simply toggle Collase and Expand with the changing icon

Comment: @Dave123 As I said  wrap `<span>Collapse Views</span>` and as 
freedomn-m said is to check the classes not the html .. this is the best way

Comment: An alternative is to have 2x icons *already in the HTML* then toggle the visibility of them.  This would be an alternative and not necessarily "better" (less code as you just toggle a class and let css handle the visibility)

Comment: @Dave123 I updated the answer with the good way to do this